# how to scale gif image to fill full screen (all sizes)

Tags: android, image, android-studio, scale, gif

I made a splash page with `gif` image as you see in this layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Splash">

    <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/fneclis_splash_bg"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I created all layout sizes (small, normal, large and xlarge) and I did the same thing to the `gif` image (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi).

My problem is the small layout takes the mdpi gif image size, the normal layout takes the xxhdpi image size and the same problem for the other layouts.

i think maybe the problem is here because it contain some lines about Title and the full screen
this is the Splash code :

```
package com.medanis.fneclis

import android.content.DialogInterface
import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewConfiguration
import android.view.Window
import android.view.WindowManager
import android.widget.MediaController
import pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifDrawable
import pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageButton

class Splash : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        //hiding title bar of this activity
        window.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        //making this activity full screen
       window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash)

        //2.63second splash time
        Handler().postDelayed({
            //start main activity
            startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
            //finish this activity
            finish()
        },2630)


        val gib = GifImageButton(this)
        setContentView(gib)
        gib.setImageResource(R.drawable.fneclis_splash_bg)
        val mc = MediaController(this)
        mc.setMediaPlayer(gib.drawable as GifDrawable)
        mc.setAnchorView(gib)
        gib.setOnClickListener(object : DialogInterface.OnClickListener, View.OnClickListener {
            override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
                mc.show()
            }

            override fun onClick(p0: DialogInterface?, p1: Int) {
                mc.show()
            }

        })

    }
}
```

What might be the reason for this? Help me please and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:scaleType="fitXY" to android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

OK, so centerCrop is used to uniformly scale the image while maintaining the image or in your case the gif's aspect ratio. Whereas in the case of fitXY it just fits the parent view of the image does not consider the aspect ratios.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @rohiththammaiah Please edit that comment into your answer. Answers with only code get auto-flagged for low quality post review. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/20632120)

Comment: the problem is here       gib.setImageResource(R.drawable.fneclis_splash_bg)
this code takes only one image size